# What is a MYSQL - Delayed insert?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

*I am a MySQL/MariaDB newbie.*

---

I have an application that inserts lots of data, in short bursts, to a MariaDB database.
The series of tests (or runs) stops consistently at 30 seconds and never completes (if I set the runtime in the app to 10 seconds it works, but is of no value).

DB and app are hosted on a Linux tower dedicated only to this application.  It is connected to a NetApp for user directories.

A snippet of my processlist while the task is running:

```
Id  |user     |host                   |db  |command       |time|state             |info |progress
1345|myuser   |server.company.com:1234|MyDB|sleep         |268 |                  |      | 0.000
1319|DELAYED  |localhost              |MyDB|Delayed insert|131 |Waiting for insert|       |0.000
```

I have lots of connections on the DB in SLEEP state and one is always "Delayed insert"

What I have done thus far:

1. *delayed_queue_size* from default to 5000
2. vmstat to see if anything is blocking a process - *none found*
3. deleting all the databases the app creates and trying over again

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT1:

*Here are some new data points that I'm allowed to post:*

I enabled logging and found the following:

```
[WARNING] aborted connection 1234 to db: 'mydb" user: 'myuser' host: 'company.com' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

I used tcpdump and listened on the interface, lo (local host).

I found the following

1. create table `mytab`.`tab` (myunique key) engine **MyISAM** commet='{"owner":"Me"}'    INSERT ...
2. A call to read a file from a NetApp, `10.XXX.XX.12:/vol/n02vol2/data`
3. The last line from the tcdump was: `Select count(*) from information_schema.TAB`  *(truncated)*

The putty connection times out after 5 minutes of inactivity.

MariaDB is a 5 version

Comment: Have you read [INSERT DELAYED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-delayed.html) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-delayed.html) ?

Comment: From what I found online it seems to be related to replication ..  But I'll read your link, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are using MyISAM.  You should change to ENGINE=InnoDB.

InnoDB allows multiple concurrent `INSERTs` in many cases.  The "delayed" feature of MyISAM is essentially unnecessary in InnoDB, and the keyword is probably just silently ignored.

I suspect you have encountered a case where MyISAM is slower (perhaps significantly) than InnoDB.

This may show a value of 1800 (30 minutes):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';
```

If you could share the queries (both the dying one and the blocker) and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, we might have further tips.

Comment: I did find MyISAM in the log.  The DB is InnoDB | DEFAULT.  Can I force the DB to ignore the call to the MyISAM engine?  Does that really solve the "error reading communication packets" errors?

Comment: @Marinaio - Yes, there is some such setting (I don't remember what it is.)  Meanwhile, you should do `ALTER TABLE name ENGINE=InnoDB;` for each table.  it will take a long time if the table is huge.  I _think_ the real problem is some long-running locks, not communication.